# Cannot apply simple OLS model in the case of low resolution devices resulting in Fourier space convolution

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, model, biostatistics, convolution

There's a problem which often comes up within my field and doesn't seem to be approachable analytically. Any suggestions or direction towards the class of problems this falls under would be helpful.

First consider a OLS problem

$$
d_n = A(\lambda_n)\exp\Big(-\sum_i c_i \epsilon(\lambda_n)\Big),
$$

so that

$$
-\ln(d_n/A(\lambda_n)) = \sum_i c_i \epsilon(\lambda_n),
$$

and the linear regression problem may be solved straightforwardly to obtain the desired $c_i$s.

However, frequently we encounter situations where a range of wavelengths are detected by the detector, so

$$
d_n = \int_{\lambda_{\mathrm{min}}}^{\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}} A(\lambda) \exp\Big(-\sum_i c_i \epsilon(\lambda_n)\Big) \mathrm{d}\lambda
$$

This is basically a convolution in Fourier space. In practice, $\lambda_{\mathrm{min}}$, $\lambda_{\mathrm{max}}$ may be taken as $+\infty$, $-\infty$ respectively with the domain of $A(\lambda)$ restricted. This problem is clearly no longer OLS, and the standard trick of isolating $\sum_i c_i \epsilon(\lambda_n)$ no longer works. Any suggestions or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a nonlinear regression.  The best way to obtain solutions depends on your assumptions, constraints, and the size of the problem (principally the number of $c_i$ to estimate).

Comment: @whuber can you direct me towards any papers which solve this sort of problem with integrals?

Comment: You tagged this question with `biostatistics`, but the relationship of the question to that field isn't immediately obvious. Editing the question to say more about the biological application might lead to some suggestions about how to solve this problem, based on similar biostatistical problems.